# how to make parallax scroll view with tabs in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i currently try to make some scroll view with tab bar.

and if i scroll down, tab bar is fixed on the top.

this is the example i want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITZHJ.gif

if you know how to make this or NPM i can use, please let me know if you have it.

thanks for reading!!

this is i try by my self but failed..

```js
        <Animated.ScrollView
          scrollEventThrottle={5}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.nScroll}}}],
            {useNativeDriver: true},
          )}
          style={{zIndex: 0}}>
          <Animated.View
            style={{
              transform: [
                {translateY: Animated.multiply(this.nScroll, 0.65)},
                {scale: this.imgScale},
              ],
              backgroundColor: THEME_COLOR,
            }}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `FlatList` that have `stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}` for keeping `ListHeaderComponent` sticky, and the `data` passed in depend on tab state

```
const [ tab, setTab ] = useState(1)
// you should add at least keyExtractor and renderItem props...
<FlatList
    stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
    ListHeaderComponent={ <Tabs setTab={setTab} /> } // create `Tabs` component of the nav, use `props.setTab` to change `tab` state
    data={ tab == 1 ? tab1data : tab2data } // assuming tab1data is array 
/>
```

more about `FlatList` https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist